# How to re-implement the expandable feature of email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins

Many email clients now provide expandable feature. if you have a threaded email(the one that has multiple replies), usually the email client only show the "new" message on top. Underneath the new message there is usually a expandable button and if you click on it you will see the whole email conversation.

I want to have the same feature in my APP. Now I can retrieve the email body html code by using Office.js or EWS API, but when I render the code I will only see the whole conversation. Where is the expandable thing gone? How can I reverse engineer this? The closest thing I can get so far is using EWS API's `Unique Body` to just get the latest bit of the conversation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently this feature is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

[Outlook Add-ins Engineering Team]